# Regex - maximum 255 chars, no space at start and end,

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am trying to create a regex for a html5 input that should only contain a valid folder name.

To support a wide variety of file systems, I thought about only allowing:

1. Minimum length is 1 character between a-Z and 0-9
2. During the middle spaces are allowed, but not at the start or end
3. Allow maximum 255 characters

Now my regex looks like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,254}[a-zA-Z0-9]?
```

The question mark in the end is a problem, because that would allow spaces at the end, if no end character is given.

But if I leave it out, I need to add at least 2 characters.
Similar problem appears if I add the `?` to the first pattern.

Now I am stuck. I can do it without the character restriction of 255 but with it everything falls apart.

Comment: Why not enclose the middle and end groups together in `()` and make that optional with `?` Then the first group is always required, and the last is only required in conjunction with the middle.

Comment: Argh, so near, yet so far away :) - would also need to be {0, 253} to never exceed the 255 chars, right? (Or is my math broken as well?)

Comment: The right answer is `[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?`: HTML5 attribute anchors the pattern automatically behind the scenes, and the `?`  quantifier should be applied to the group of the 2nd and 3rd atoms in the original regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^\b[A-Z\d ]{1,255}\b$/i
```

- [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

---

HTML5 input check: `pattern="\b[A-Za-z\d ]{1,255}\b"`

Comment: not sure what the `/i` is for, but very elegant indeed!

Comment: Excellent use of `\b` ++ deserves to be accepted answer

Comment: `/i` is to make the matches case insensitive (eliminates the need for `[A-Za-z]` type syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add ^ at start and $ at end only then your regex will need to match the entire tested line. Otherwise it can match 255 characters out of 100000 and it will still pass.

Comment: This answer is not correct in the context of HTML5 `pattern` attribute used by OP. There is no need to use `^` and `$` explicitly in the pattern, they are added automatically when the string pattern is passed to the RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]$|^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

The first alternative handles the single character case, and the second part the 2-255 character case.

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]$|^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9]$` like this, or? :)

Comment: There is no need to use `^` and `$` explicitly in the pattern, they are added automatically when the string pattern is passed to the RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.* $)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,254}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q46hQ5/3/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]`: Match an alpha-numerical character at start
- `(?!.* $)`: Negative lookahead to assert failure when last character is a space
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,254}`: Match 0 to `254` alpha-numerical or space characters
- `$`: End